# Windows 8 Pro denies NAS access

Tags: windows, nas

I just upgraded my system to win8 pro (a clean install of course) and everything runs as it should - besides that Windows denies me to access my Netgear ReadyNAS Duo. I can see that it is connected to my network, since it has been given an IP. That is pretty much it though. I can't see the drive in the Network section, can't map it or access it.

The drive itself is fine, since I can access it from my other machine running win7.

Has anybody experienced something similiar and/or knows a workaround until microsoft fixes the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably related:  http://superuser.com/q/483958/60719

Comment: Hi Steve, really good thought, but it didn't fix it.